# Android: How to get the screenshot of ViewGroup when there is TextureView which has alpha color

Tags: android, alpha, ondraw, textureview

I am trying to get the screenshot of the viewGroup, which has three sub views, at the background is a imageView, and then TextureView to draw something(maybe translucent), and at the top is another imageView.

When call the View.draw(), the content of the TextureView will not be captured. So when begin capturing, I call the TextureView.getBitmap to get its content, then replace the TextureView with the imageView(whose image is the content of the TextureView).

While the color changed, and I tried to draw the image onto the screenshot, never worked, I tried every mode of PorterDuff.

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkQdZ.png)

The left is the appearance of the View, the right is the screenshot I captured.

Who has any suggestion? thanks very much.